# Нужно ли переносить файлы .jks (ключи) при переносе проектов Android Studio на другой компьютер?

Tags: android-studio

Планирую перенести все проекты Android Studio на другой ПК. Так как я до конца не разобрался как работают ключи, у меня встает вопрос. Нужно ли вместе с проектами переносить ключи? Что будет если этого не сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, это необходимо сделать, так как без них вам не удастся сгенерировать валидные подписанные `bundle` или `apk` и придется восстанавливать эти ключи через Google Play Console.

Answer (score 2):

Во первых: переносить проект без ключа можно. Для разработки он не нужен. Нужен только для публикации в магазине.

Во вторых: если вы не отдали в консоль релизный ключ, то не сможете перевыпустить `upload`-ключ! Т.е. если вы загружаете в консоль `Apk` и потеряли ключ, то восстановить его не возможно. Вы сможете перевыпустить upload-ключ только если перешли на `App Bundle`.

Это ответ на ваш вопрос и на ответ @Dareten

Comment: Я не говорил, что этого делать нельзя, но если у человека уже имеются ключи для проектов, то логично предположить, что он ими пользуется. А учитывая то, что не все используют Bundle, этот перенос становится ещё более актуален.

Comment: Вы ввели в заблуждение, написав, что если он загружает Apk, то сможет восстановить ключ. Знаете, такие слова расслабляют, а это очень серьезно.